# Deleting video id of the video while downloading via youtube-dl

Tags: bash, shell, youtube-dl

I'm downloading a full YouTube playlist, but I don't want to save the video id.

For example, I've downloaded those files:

```
Lecture 1 - Course Logistics and Introduction to SwiftUI-jbtqIBpUG7g.en.vtt
Lecture 1 - Course Logistics and Introduction to SwiftUI-jbtqIBpUG7g.mp4
Lecture 10 - Navigation + TextField-CKexGQuIO7E.en.srt.vtt
Lecture 10 - Navigation + TextField-CKexGQuIO7E.mp4
```

I want it to be:

```
Lecture 1 - Course Logistics and Introduction to SwiftUI.en.srt.vtt
Lecture 1 - Course Logistics and Introduction to SwiftUI.mp4
Lecture 10 - Navigation + TextField.en.vtt
Lecture 10 - Navigation + TextField.mp4
```

How can I get it done?

Comment: Welcome to SO. On SO we do encourage users to do add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems in their questions, its highly encouraged. So kindly do add the same in your question and let us know then.

Comment: `How can I get it done?` Download the file, then open your file explorer of choice and navigate to the directory with the file, then rename the files and remove the `-somethingsomething` part before the dot.

Comment: Something like: `echo "Lecture 1 - Course Logistics and Introduction to SwiftUI-jbtqIBpUG7g.mp4" | sed 's/\-[a-zA-Z0-9]\+//`

Answer (score 2):

You can tell it to only include the title and extension by using -o

`youtube-dl -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" video_url`