# Do not append video id youtube-dl

Tags: shell, youtube-dl

Is there any way to prevent the name of the downloaded file having part of the video ID attacted? An example of what I mean:
If you run:

```
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
```

You will get a file called "Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up (Video)-dQw4w9WgXcQ.mp4"
I would like to not have that garble of text attacthed to the end of my videos. Is there an option or flag I am missing to disable this feature?

Comment: So did you read [`youtube-dl` documentation](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/youtube-dl.1.html)? There's literally a whole section named `OUTPUT TEMPLATE`, looks super interesting to read. Literally `Examples` in that section has ready answer for you. Please consider first reading the `man youtube-dl` page of the utility before asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting video id of the video while downloading via youtube-dl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63353489/deleting-video-id-of-the-video-while-downloading-via-youtube-dl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [man youtube-dl](https://man.archlinux.org/man/community/youtube-dl/youtube-dl.1.en):

> -o, --output TEMPLATE
>
> Output filename template, see the "OUTPUT TEMPLATE" for all the info
>
> [...]
>
> The current default template is %(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s.

Just drop the `id`.

```
youtube-dl -o '%(title)s.%(ext)s' ...
```

Comment: This works! I guess I should have read the docs a bit more carefully. Thanks! :)